# How to add a new text to existing one and identify specific user in php+mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to make a form where people can add some info, and that will add up to the existing info in the table in mysql. Like lets say the "dates" column, i have info such as 05.05.2020, 01.05.2020. And i want to ADD 11.05.2020 to near of the 05.05.2020, and 01.05.2020. When i do that, it just erases this info and adds only 11.05.2020. But i want it to look like 05.05.2020, 01.05.2020,11.05.2020.
And the second thing which i dont know how to do, is how to match the users form input with the data within the mysql? Lets say in form it says Username:, Date:. Username puts 0001, and php takes that value and matches it with mysql username column. If it exists, it adds date to that specific users table.
Here is my code:
html:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php">
<center>
<label for="accnum">Username</label><br>
<br>
<input type="text"  name="accnum" id="accnum"><br>
<br>
<label for="date">Date</label><br>
<input type="text"  name="date" id="date"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and my process.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "jbex");


if($link === false){
    die("w. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$accnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['accnum']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date']);


$sql = "UPDATE accounts (date) VALUES ( '$date' WHERE $accnum=?)";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "success.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

What to put near WHERE "$accnum=" so it takes the users input with the form named accnum?
Thanks for reading and help

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the MySQL UPDATE query also appears to be incorrect. Consult the documentation on [`UPDATE` query syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). Your query should probably look closer to this.

```sql
UPDATE accounts SET date = ? WHERE accnum = ?
```

It looks like you're overwriting the value of the `date` column with the value provided by the user, where you say you're wanting to instead add the value to your existing data for that user.

MySQL doesn't support list types, so you'd have to either store the dates using a different column type (e.g. `varchar` or `text`) or store the dates as rows in a separate table where each row in that table includes the primary key value for its respective user.

You should also be using a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with a bound parameter for the values of the `date` value you want to add and the `accnum` value for the record you want to add that value to.